# generate top k values

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I have a problem and I want to make sure if I am doing it most efficiently. I have an array A of float values of size N. The values are all between 0 and 1.

I have to find top k values which can be a product of a maximum of three numbers from A. So, the top-k list can
have individual numbers from A, product of two numbers or product of three numbers from A.

So, this is how I am doing it now. I can get top-k numbers in desecding order in O(Nlogk) time. I then create a 
max-heap and initialize it with  best values of maximum size 3 i.e. if I represent the sorted array(descending) of k values as B
and the numbers by its index in that array, I insert numbers which are at index (0), (0,1) and (0,1,2). Next, I perform extract on heap and 
whenever I extract a size z (product of z numbers) value, I replace it with the set of next possible size z numbers i.e.
if suppose (2,4) is extracted, I can replace it with (3,4) and (2,5). And do extract k times to get results.

Need better ideas if you have.
Thanks all.

Comment: Are you sure you don't add the same number twice? For example, (1,3) goes both after (1,2) and (0,3)

Comment: right, I didn't mention it but we have to make sure we don't add something twice, probably using a hash table

Comment: @user: Since your numbers are all between 0 and 1, the product of any two numbers from your set will be smaller than both of these numbers (or equal to the smaller if one of them is 1, equal to both if both are 1). So, the top k will always be individual numbers. Is that correct, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: yes, the product of two numbers a,b will be smaller than the individual numbers. But, a*b can be larger than c,d,.... (a>b>c>d>....)

Comment: May be a stupid doubt, but still to back up Space_C0wb0y`s comment. Do we actually need to tabulate if the particular number is the product of 2 or 3 individual numbers, if the list can contain the top k which can contain individual numbers as well :-D

Comment: as I said, consider numbers 0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5,..... in sorted order. t is easy to see that 0.9*0.8 > 0.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you correctly you need to find k highest numbers that can be produced by multiplying together 1, 2 or 3 elements from your list, and all the values are floating point numbers between 0 and 1.

It is clear that you only need to consider the k highest numbers from the list. The rest can be discarded straight away. You can use your O(n log k) algorithm to get them, again in sorted order (I assume your list isn't preordered). To simplify the problem, you can now take their logarithms and try to maximize the sums of the numbers instead of the original problem of maximizing the products. This might speed up little.

Now (considering the logarithmic presentation), all your numbers are negative, so adding more of them together will just create more and more negative numbers.

Let's call the k highest numbers A1...Ak. We can reduce the problem further now assuming that there exists also number A0, that has the value 0 in the log representation and 1 in the original representation; then the problem is to enumerate the first k 3-tuples  (x,y,z in {A0,...,Ak}) with the constraint that x ≥ y ≥ z and that z < A0. Let's denote 3-tuple  by [i,j,n] and the sum of the elements in this tuple by S[i,j,n]. The first element to be reported is obviously [0,0,1], i.e. , which corresponds in the original problem formulation to the singleton #1 value on the list.

We use a max-heap as in the original formulation; we push the triples to the heap, using their sums (S[...]) as the ordering key. The algorithm starts by pushing [0,0,0] to the heap. Then:

```
answer = []
for m in 0 .. k:
  top = heap.pop()
  answer.append(sum(top))
  (i,j,n) = top # explode the tuple
  if (n < k - 1):
      heap.push((i,j,n+1))
  if (j == n):
      heap.push((i,j+1,j+1))
      if (i == j):
          heap.push((i+1,i+1,i+1))
```

At the end, answer contains k + 1 elements, the first one of them is [0,0,0] which must be discarded.

Let  be given as -1, -3, -8, -9. Then the algorithm proceeds like this:

```
Heap
Top          Rest (shown in order)

[ 0, 0, 0] | 
[ 0, 0,-1] | [ 0,-1,-1] [-1,-1,-1]
[ 0,-1,-1] | [-1,-1,-1] [ 0,-1,-3] [ 0,-3,-3]
[-1,-1,-1] | [-1,-1,-2] [ 0,-1,-3] [-1,-2,-2] [-2,-2,-2] [ 0,-3,-3]
[-1,-1,-2] | [ 0,-1,-3] [-1,-1,-3] [-1,-2,-2] [-2,-2,-2] [ 0,-3,-3]
[ 0,-1,-3] | [-1,-1,-3] [ 0,-1,-4] [-1,-2,-2] [-2,-2,-2] [ 0,-3,-3]
[-1,-1,-3] | [ 0,-1,-4] [-1,-1,-4] [-1,-2,-2] [-2,-2,-2] [ 0,-3,-3]
[ 0,-1,-4] | [-1,-2,-2] [-1,-1,-4] [ 0,-1,-5] [-2,-2,-2] [ 0,-3,-3]
...
etc.
```

The nice thing about this algorithm is that it doesn't enumerate duplicates and the heap size is O(k); to see why, observe that the algorithm adds on every iteration the maximum of elements on the heap (often less), so after k iterations there cannot be more than 2k elements in the heap.

This gives then running time O(n log k + k log k) = O((n + k) log k).

Comment: Hmm there is likely a bug in the iteration algorithm ... It can be still linear time but the iteration order is not that simple because the might be ordered (a1,a1), (a1,a2), (a1,a3), (a2,a2), (a1,a4) --- I'll update the answer tomorrow

Comment: yes, was thinking the same..probably can't do without a heap but i like the log optimization

Comment: Ok, I rewrote it to use a heap... it should be an improvement on your algorithm if you add (3,4), (2,5) to the heap once you pop (2,4), then when you next pop (2,5) you would add (3,5) and (2,6). This is suboptimal, you don't need to have (3,5) in the heap because (3,4) is there already and when you pop now (3,4), you will re-generate the successor element (3,5). Then you need to have another datastructure to detect duplicates.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just one more question: how would it change your algorithm, if I say that we are  allowed to take an element only once in any one sum(or product). So in the example given above, the output order should be like: -1, -3, (-1+-3), -8, (-1+-8)(or -9)

Comment: Well the easiest change is just to throw away those tuples :) the second easiest is to change the rules by which new tuples are added to the heap, i.e. add (i,j+1,j+2) instead of (...,j+1) and add (i+1,i+2,i+3) instead of (i+1,i+1,i+1); this will cause the tuples with multiple entries to be skipped over.

Comment: You can find [the k largest value in O(n) time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n/4956638#4956638). This makes the overall complexity O(n+k log k).

Answer (score 1):

I certainly see an optimization you could make.

```
Let M be the highest number from A.
Let M2 be M * M.
Let setMM2 consist of all x from A such that M2 < x < M
If size(setMM2) >= k, 
    then your top-k consist of the highest k elements.
Else
    all x in setMM2 are in your top-k and your search becomes smaller
```

You can repeat this method with max(secondHighestNumber^2,M^3) and generalize the algorithm.

Comment: if we talk about fast algorithms, we should also give an expected running time, shouldn't we? :)

Comment: @duedl0r as far as I'm aware this will not give you a guaranteed improvement in complexity, as the worst case scenario, setMM2 is empty and you're right back where you started. The performance boost from this is entirely data dependent. **However** it has been my experience from working with such algorithms that when you have a non-guaranteed improvement in complexity, thinking along the same lines as the suggestion can lead you to a guaranteed improvement in complexity. My hope is that this (potentially large or small) boost can open the door to OP finding an even better solution.

Answer (score 0):

kNSince numbers are from 0 to 1, more numbers you use, the worst it gets and problem is whit big k, for instance k=N^2

First try whit single numbers and push then in heap. O(N*Log(k))

Than use this numbers from heap and make another heap B whit 2 numbers => O(k*log(k)) at worst, but you can do some speedups if you sort numbers in case k>N

And then You have heap whit 2 numbers and there products and try making 3rd heap C from heap B same way as you would do for B, but from much bigger heap.

I think that this will make a O(k*log(k))

Comment: this isn't better than what I propose

Comment: I made another complexity assumpion