# How to find the third maximum value in matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

I want to find the third maximum value in matrix.
I already have the max value

```
max(A)
```

And I already have second max value

```
max(A(A~=max(A))
```

But i cannot do the third one, please advice and help me.

Comment: related question: [Find n minimum values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774860/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to sort the values of `A` in descending order, and pick the third sorted element (if it exists):

```
A_sorted = sort(A(:), 'descend');
third_max = A_sorted(min(3, end));
```

If you don't allow repeating values (*e.g* `A = [10, 10; 9; 2]` and want 2), sort the unique values:

```
A_sorted = sort(unique(A), 'descend');
```