# HashMap iteration/Deletion

Tags: java, list, iterator, hashmap

I'm trying to process a large amount of data and I'm a bit stuck on the best way to process the final calculation.

I have a HashMap. Each Book object has a data value called COUNT that holds how many times that book appears in my particular context. I want to iterate through the entire HashMap and do record the top ten most-appearing books in an array. At the same time, I also want to remove those top ten books from the HashMap. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you done? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I read other SO posts that stated that it's not possible to delete items mid-iteration if you use the for-each construct--would it be better to use an iterator?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to remove them inline instead of after? How can you even know which 10 are the highest until you've iterated the entire map?

Comment: when you use a iterator instead of for-each it is possible to remove items during iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't remove using a `for` loop because like this

```
for(Book curBook: yourMap.values())
```

You will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. To remove elements while iterating, you have to use an iterator, for example:

```
HashMap<Book> yourMap;

Collection<Book> entries = yourMap.values();
Iterator<Book> iterator = entries.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Book curBook = iterator.next();
    if (yourConditionToRemove) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

If this is a frequent operation, consider using TreeMap as suggested by Bohemian or at least keep a separate Map with most read Books.

Comment: You can still use a for loop, just in a different way - `for(Iterator<Book> iterator = entries.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)`  And this has the advantage of scoping the iterator to the iteration, whereas the while loop has the iterator scoped outside of the loop.

Comment: Yes, I know, I meant foreach loop the OP is commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the map into a SortedMap, such as TreeMap, using a comparator that compares the count.

The rest should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tournament algorithm that runs in O(n) time and can be useful for large data ,

[Optimal algorithm for returning top k values from an array of length N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n)

If the data is not very huge then I would recommend using Collections.sort and creating a subList from your Map.

Another option is it to keep them in TreeMap and implement Comparable in your Book Object , that way your Map is always sorted . This is particularly useful if you are doing additions to your Map as you don't want to sort them every time you change an object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that proficient at Java, but I can think about the following algorithm. Assuming that the HashMap stores books according to their unique identifier (i.e. it gives you no ordering hints about `COUNT`). You can:

1. Define a sequence with capacity for ten books in which they will be stored ordered by `COUNT`. For clarity, I will call this sequence `O10S` (Ordered 10-element sequence)
2. Traverse your hashmap. For each element `e` in `HashMap`:

   - If `O10S` is not full yet insert `e` in `O10S`
   - Otherwise, if `e` has a `COUNT` higher than the element `o` in `O10S` with the minimum `COUNT` (which should be easily identifiable since `O10S` is ordered): remove `o` from `O10S`, insert `e` in `O10S`
3. For every `o` in `O10S`, remove `o` from `HashMap`

The algorithm is linear with respect of the elements in `HashMap` (you only need to traverse the `HashMap` once)