# How to find k biggest numbers from a list of n numbers assuming n > k

Tags: python, list, max

I am looking for some code in Python which could return `k` largest numbers from an unsorted list of `n` numbers. First I thought to do this by sorting the list first, but this might turn out to be very bulky.

For example the list from which I want to find `k` largest number be `list1`

```
> list1 = [0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
```

Here `n = 7` and if `k = 3`, that is if I want to find 3 largest numbers from a list of 7 numbers then output should be `0.5, 0.7, 0.5`

How can this be done?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n

Comment: I want the code for python. The other links to C.

Comment: No, there is not a single line of code in the link he provided, just the procedure to follow. You can easily make it into Python.

Comment: The procedure seems difficult to follow as I am new to programming and python. I was wondering if there might be some way with max function which could possible get me the desired output straight away. Further, I am taking part in a programming tournament and I am restricted to create my own functions :(

Comment: In which case asking on SO for actual code rather than pointers would be cheating...

Comment: I am not cheating. The exact question is not what I am asking for. It's just a part which can just help build me the code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Python has all batteries included - use [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module :)

```
from heapq import nlargest

data = [0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
print nlargest(3, data)
```

it's also faster than sorting the whole array, because it's using partial heapsort

Comment: This is a better solution. Took me about an year to figure that out.

Comment: if you're interested in the indexes for example, you can use the 'key' parameter. nlargest(3, range(len(data)), key=lambda idx: data[idx]).

Answer (score 3):

It can be done like this:

```
>>> list1
[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
>>> list2 = list1[:] #make a copy of list1
>>> k = 3
>>> result = []
>>> for i in range(k):
        result.append(max(list2)) #append largest element to list of results
        list2.remove(max(list2)) # remove largest element from old list
>>> result
[0.7, 0.5, 0.5]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want to modify `list1`, you make a [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) copy:

```
In [1]: list1 = [0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

In [2]: list2 = sorted(list1)

In [3]: list2
Out[3]: [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7]
```

In `list2`, the largest numbers are the last numbers, so we'll use [slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
In [4]: list2[-3:]
Out[4]: [0.5, 0.5, 0.7]
```

The links I've added point to Pythons [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html). As a beginner, you should start with having a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html). After that, the [library reference](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html) is what you'll be needing most, because the large standard library is one of the things that makes python so nice.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This was exactly what I was looking for. I was working really hard to sort a list when there exist a nice sorted(list1) function. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```py
import numpy as np
k = 3
ind = np.argpartition(list1, -k)[-k:] # index of the k highest elements
print(list1[ind])
```

Comment: I admire this answer, as I believe it should take up less time than the other solutions (though I haven't strictly "timed-it" along with the others).  Now, a subsidiary question: can this index be sorted as to take the highest index first, second-highest next, and so on ?

Answer (score 0):

without sorting, using a greedy approach

```
k_largest = list1[:k]
for num in list1:
    for c in range(k):
        if num > k_largest[c]:
            k_largest = k_largest[:c] + [num] + k_largest[c:-1]  # maintains sorted order
            break
print(k_largest)
```