# Nlargest element in list

Tags: python

Is there is anyway to compute N Largest element in a list without foor loop?

```
def Nlargest(list):
     #your code here
     #print n largest element of a list without for loop
```

Comment: You can do this: `max(lst)`

Comment: what do you mean by nlargest? the maximum? if so, you can find with ```max([1, 2, 3])``` will print 3

Comment: `sorted(list, reverse=True)[:n]`?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906949/how-to-find-k-biggest-numbers-from-a-list-of-n-numbers-assuming-n-k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def Nlargest(list):
    import heapq
   print(heapq.nlargest(n,list))  #return a list of n largest element
```

I hope this would help you

Answer (score 2):

If you care about performance, you can find an implementation of the [Quick-Select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm.
It runs in linear runtime, opposed to *n log n* for algorithms which rely on sorting.

If runtime isn't important, you can take one of the suggestion in the comments.

Comment: quick-select finds the nth largest, not the n largest...

Comment: You're right, should've clarified that. But you can get the n largest from that easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list and print the last n elemets(largest n elements in the list) as follows

```
def Nlargest(list):
    list.sort()        # first sort the list
    print(list[-n:])   # print the last n elements as they will be the largest ones
```

A short hand for the code (which doesn't mutate the original list) above would be -

```
def Nlargest(list):
    print(sorted(list, reverse=True)[:n]) #sort in descending order and print first n elements
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: That isn't a short-hand, that is doing something totally different. The first *mutates* the input and returns a new list, the second simply returns a new list, without mutating the input. You should prefer the second.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added it