# Iterating through ArrayList to get 5 Largest Numbers

Tags: java

Yes, this is homework, but I need some help with it. I have been able to make it sort through the highest number, but none of the numbers are correct after that. List of numbers: http://pastebin.com/Ss1WFGv1
Right now, we are learning arrays, so is this simply trying to shoot a fly with a cannonball?

```
    package hw2;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class HW2 {

        public static ArrayList<Integer> nums1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        public static int size = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ArrayList<Integer> sortedNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();


            readFile();
            System.out.println("Name: Jay Bhagat" + "\n" + "Email: xxxxxx");
            size = nums1.size();

            for(int l = 0; l<=10;l++){
            nums1.set(sortThis(nums1, l), 90009);
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            }


    //        for (int k = 0; k <= size - 1; k++) {
    //            System.out.println("Number " + (k + 1) + sortedNums.get(k));
    //
    //        }


        }

        public static void readFile() throws Exception {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("L:\\numbers.txt"));

            while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                nums1.add(Integer.parseInt((reader.readLine())));
            }

            reader.close();


        }

        public static int sortThis(ArrayList<Integer> current, int offset) {
            int j = 0;
            int tempNum = 0;
            int curNum = 0;
            int finalIndex = 0;
            int prevIndex = 0;
            int curIndex = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < size-offset; j++) {
                curIndex = j;
                nums1.trimToSize();
                curNum = current.get(j);
                //Thread.sleep(1000);
                if(curNum!=90009){
                if (curNum > tempNum) {
                    tempNum = curNum;
                    System.out.println(tempNum);
                    prevIndex = j;
                    finalIndex = prevIndex;
                }
                if (curNum < tempNum) {
                    finalIndex = prevIndex;
                }
                }    



            }
            return finalIndex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: After you sort the array / list, why not just grab the last 5 elements?

Comment: This is actually a pretty good problem to ask in an interview. Obviously without the sorting part...  25 % credit for asking if there are duplicate numbers in the list.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n

Answer (score 3):

An approach that lets you make just one pass through the list and doesn't require sorting:

Declare an array of 5 integers: `int[] largest = new int[5];`

Put the first 5 elements in the `ArrayList` into `largest`.

Starting with the 6th element, look at each element N in the `ArrayList`, and if N is larger than *any* element in `largest`, throw out the smallest number currently in `largest` and replace it with N.

If you need to exclude duplicates, the algorithm can be modified easily (just skip over any `ArrayList` element that's already in `largest`).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Collections.sort(List list) or Arrays.Sort(arr). This will save much of effort. Or is it part of your task?

Comment: yeah, sorting is part of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your collection is sorted, and you want the last 5 elements, try this out:

```
for (int i = sortedNums.size() - 5; i < sortedNums.size(); ++i) {
  System.err.println(sortedNums.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need two lines of code:

```
Collections.sort(nums1);
List<Integer> high5 = nums1.subList(nums1.size() - 5, nums1.size());
```

If you must "do it yourself", the simplest way to sort is a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort):

- iterate over the list
- swap adjacent numbers if they are in the wrong order
- repeat n times

Not efficient but very easy to code.

Comment: Although I'm sure that collections are a good way to sort the numbers, I'm not sure that my professor would take kindly to code that I do not understand myself.

Comment: Just to let you know: No one in the real world *ever* writes their own sorting algorithm. Everyone uses Collections.sort(), maybe with a custom Comparator when a custom order is needed. Learning the JDK API *is* learning the language. Same applies to every language actually.

Comment: True, but is this really a question of the faults of programming professors? I have to do this or I get an F on the assignment. Although I wholeheartedly agree that I would never reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: Ok, so after fitzing around, I have decide to just use bubblesort. It's inefficient, sure, but it gets the job done and I only have like 1000 elements. Thank you!

Comment: It would be:
List<Integer> high5 = nums1.subList(0,5);
since the List is already sorted.

Comment: @MIKEPERETZ incorrect. `Collection.sort()` sorts in *ascending* order, so we need to return the *last* 5 to get the largest numbers (as per question title). Your suggestion would require sorting in *descending* order, so you would have to write a custom `Comparator`, which at the time of writing this answer would have required creating an anonymous class, which is more complicated and less readable than some simple math using the size of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

How I would go about doing this:

Create a temporary ArrayList, as a copy of the initial one.
After each largest element is found, remove it from the temporary ArrayList and add it to your 5 largest numbers

Repeat until complete

edit* This does not require your elements to be sorted, and has a fairly poor efficiency as a result

Comment: Since doing it this way is O(n) (you search linearly through the array 5 times), and sorting is at best O(n log n), at some point your method will be more efficient than sorting first, if the list is large enough, except for the "remove" part, since removing from an `ArrayList` can shift a lot of elements.  Improvements would be to use a `LinkedList` so that removal time is constant, or "remove" an element by changing it to Integer.MIN_VALUE so that no shifting is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do not have the liberty to use `sort` and suchlike, considering this is a homework. So here is outline of an algorithm that you can try to implement

```
 create an array of five integers (we will keep this sorted)
 for each element in the list
   find the index of the element in the array that it is greater than
   if no such element exists in the array (i.e. it is smaller than all elements in the array)
     continue on to the next element in the list
   else
     push all elements in the array to one index below, letting them fall off the 
     edge if need be (e.g. if the number in list is 42 and the array has 
     45 and 40 at index 3 and 2 respectively then 
     move arr[1] to arr[0], and arr[2] (40) to arr[1] and set arr[2] = 42)
   end if
 end for
```

At the end the array will have the five elements

I will leave one question for you to answer (it is important): what should you set the array to initially?