# Javascript: Best way to sort array of length N and get top m

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a huge array of length over 200,000. I need to get top 10 values. I know sort is not the best solution. I have tried the following solution:

```
const sortBy = 'key';
const results = [];
const m = 10;
const N = array.length;

while (array.length && results.length < m) {
    let currentMax = 0;
    let currentMaxIndex = 0;
    array.forEach((record, i) => {
        if (record[sortBy] >= currentMax) {
            currentMax = record[sortBy];
            currentMaxIndex = i;
        }
    });
    results.push(...array.splice(currentMaxIndex, 1));
}
```

Here array is an `Array` of length 200,000.

> Problem is, I think if `m` equals `N`, then this
>   is going to take more time than `sort` itself. I want to know if there
>   is a better solution, that can handle both the cases.

---

Thank you for the help, but the actual question is `m ∈ (0, N)`. `m` can take any value up to `N`. So, at which point would it be advisable to switch to in-built `sort`?

As per my understanding as `m` reaches `N` the complexity increases and sort is the best solution when `m === N`

---

I have tested with the example provided by @t-j-crowder [here](http://jsben.ch/ppZa3). A test to get top 10 from 100 entries.

When testing with different values in `m`, the faster algorithm is changing to `sort` at `m === 85`. So, I want to find out if there is any way to determine when we should switch back to sort, to have optimal performance in all cases.

Comment: Take the first `limit` elements of the array and "assume" they're the top 10. Sort that (tiny) list. Iterate through the remaining elements of your big array. If it's bigger than the smallest element you've extracted, then drop that smallest element and insert the new one in its ordered place. Continue until you've scanned the whole array. This should be basically `O(nm)` with `n` being the size of your input and `m` being the size of your output.

Comment: iterate over, check each value against the next, store the highest in an array of `limit` size max and replace the smallest in the array until done

Comment: Consider two effective algorithms: K-select and using of K-size priority queue

Comment: **I know sort is not the best solution.** How do you know? Sorting and slicing the top 10 is the most efficient algorithm unless you use selection algorithm (median of medians -- runs on linear time) which is something complicated and most of the time more trouble than it's worth. [Here is an article on that](http://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/magic-of-selection-algorithm/)

Comment: @Redu You're kidding, right? Using Quickselect is more trouble than it's worth? My experience is much different. And the article doesn't say that it's more trouble than it's worth. In a small array, yes. But if you have a million items, sorting is going to take *much* longer than using Quickselect, or a simple heap selection algorithm. [Here's an article on that](https://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/). The difference between 28 ms and 358 ms is definitely worth the effort.

Comment: @Redu I have updated the question to clarify. I think you guys missed the actual question, the question is not just time complexity as the one i am using is also of same time complexity. The question is if there is any solution that i can use for all the values of m ∈ (0, N). I actually expected there might be a solution for that. But from the comments and answers i have figured out probably its best to use 2 different algorithms, but now the question is how to figure out at which point should I switch between the algorithms.

Comment: My use case here is number of top records to fetch is an user input, so there is a chance (however improbable it may seem) that user might request for all the records. And I want to make sure of best performance in all cases.

Comment: Yes.. as i have mentioned it seems sort & slice is not that bad. At least it's time coplexity is almost constant regardless the `k` value. @T.J. Crowder's approach is inefficient if the array is ascending even with k = 10. When the array is purely random with n = 2M, k >= 6K it again becomes inefficient compared to sort and slice. As you say growing k further literally renders it useless. You may consider checking up the quick select algorithm or some others from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to sort the whole array, you just need to insert into your top 10 array in numeric order and drop any additional entries:

```js
var a = Array.from({length:100}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000));

var check = a.slice().sort((left, right) => right - left).slice(0, 10);
console.log("check", check);

function checkResult(top10) {
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        if (top10[n] !== check[n]) {
            console.log("Error in test at #" + n + ", expected " + check[n] + ", got " + top10[n]);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var top10 = [];
var cutoff = -Infinity;
var full = false;
var n, len, value;
for (n = 0, len = a.length; n < len; ++n) {
  value = a[n];
  // If the value may be in the top 10...
  if (!full || value >= cutoff) {
    // Insert into top10
    let found = false;
    for (let n = 0; n < top10.length; ++n) {
      if (top10[n] <= value) {
        top10.splice(n, 0, value);
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      top10.push(value);
    }
    // Trim it
    if (top10.length > 10) {
      full = true;
      top10.length = 10;
    }
    // Remember the lowest of the top 10 candidates we have now so we can not bother with checking lower ones
    cutoff = top10[top10.length - 1];
  }
}

console.log("top10", top10);
console.log("Good? " + checkResult(top10));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

You can probably tidy that up a bit, optimize it further, but you get the idea. Maintaining a list of just the top 10 highest you've seen, dropping ones off the bottom if others join it.

[Benchmark here](http://jsben.ch/ppZa3), easily beats sorting and then grabbing the top 10 on Chrome and Firefox; the converse is true on Edge.

Comment: if (top10.length > 10) {
    top10.length = 10;
}

what does this do?

Comment: @AvcS It trims the array to 10 elements

Comment: Honestly think with all that effort to keep `top10` array sorted, splices and all, this must be somewhat inefficient. You may compare the performance of first sorting the big one then slicing top 10 with this one.

Comment: @Redu: I very, very, very much doubt that splicing into `top10` is going to come even close to the cost of sorting a 200,000 element array. But yes, by all means, measure it. :-)

Comment: Your code is not terribly inefficient, even in par with sort & slice with FF (mysterious case) but since you make `n` many checks on an  array with `m` items with conditional splices on top of that it's really not that efficient. In Chrome or Safari this takes 4 times longer compared to sort & slice. [Actually this is a duplicate topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n).

Comment: @Redu: Great dupetarget find! Should have know there'd be one. Care to share your performance testing code? I get the logic, but I'd be keen to see the specifics. Originally I had a check to avoid having to look in the array in the majority of cases, then it didn't work and I said "meh, to heck with it" but just now I realized why it wasn't working and added it back. Should dramatically improve efficiency.

Comment: I had looked into this a while back (in the sense of finding the kth largest element... but it's essentially similar). [This is my sloppy test code](https://repl.it/@redu/FineMintcreamJavascript)

Comment: @Redu: FWIW, I tweaked and it's much faster on Chrome and Firefox than sorting and then slicing -- interestingly, slower on Edge.

Comment: I am impressed how much checking `cutoff` value improves the performance. But..! (not a big but) This is efficient on perfectly random (which is very fine) or descending sorted arrays. Ascending array or an array with ascending chunks seems to be it's soft belly since it gradually boils down to your previous version which runs slower than sort and slice (check `Array.from({length:500000}, (_,i) => i);`). I believe you should mention your solution in the main question of this topic though.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function limitSort(array, sortBy, limit) {
    const result = [];
    // Iterate over the array *once*
    for(const el of array) {
      // Exclude all elements that are definetly not in the resulting array
      if(result.length < limit || el[sortBy] > result[0]) {
        // Determine the position were the element needs to be inserted (Insertion sort)
        let insertAt = 0;
        while(insertAt < result.length && result[insertAt][sortBy] < el[sortBy]) insertAt++;
        // Finally insert it
        result.splice(insertAt, 0, el);
        // If the results are getting to long, remove the lowest element
        if(result.length > limit)
          result.splice(0, 1);
      }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

This implements the algorithm, [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol) proposed above. [Try it!](http://jsbin.com/meyiforiwu/edit?console)

Comment: Why link to jsbin rather than use the baked in utility?

Comment: @jonSG 1) i cant because of lacking `<>` device support 2) i dont think that testcases should be part of the answer

Comment: @JonasW.: #1 is a bummer (and typical of SE, I'm afraid). #2 makes no sense to me at all. :-)