# How to get ALL LFU (Least Frequently Used) keys from Redis?

Tags: redis

Is it possible to retrieve all LFU keys from Redis database? If yes, please advice with a sample command-line.

Thanks a million,
Mughrabi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OBJECT IDLETIME` to get the number of seconds for which a key is not requested by a read or write operation. Then sort the idletimes for all keys to find LFU keys. Redis doesn't ship with a command which can print LFU keys as such. You probably have to write a script to do this.

https://redis.io/commands/OBJECT

Comment: Thanks, @rainhacker, for large systems, I see fetching all keys will cause some performance degradations, also, sorting keys based on IDLETIME will take n.log(n) time complexity, but for the business logic that I have, it works.

Comment: @AhmadAlMughrabi Glad to be of help. Few pointers on performance: 1). Use [scan](https://redis.io/commands/scan) command to avoid getting all keys at once. 2). If you need only k LFU keys, where k < n, you can do it in `O(n log(k))` time and `O(k)` space complexity using a [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n)